# Tratamento e juntar CSV no R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, ciência-de-dados

Tenho 10 csv no R e quero extrair de cada um as seguintes colunas:

```
 # A tibble: 744 × 24
   atletas.atleta_id atletas.clube_id atletas.rodada_id atletas.pontos_num atletas.jogos_num     G     A    DS    DE    SG    GS    GC    CV    CA    FC
               <int>            <int>             <int>              <dbl>             <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1             37424             1371                 2               1.84                 2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 2             72372              286                 2               0                    0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 3             37656              266                 2               6                    2    NA    NA    NA     2     2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 4             96468              285                 2               1                    2    NA    NA    NA     5    NA     3    NA    NA    NA    NA
 5             42234              264                 2              11                    2    NA    NA    NA     9     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
 6             83257              262                 2               8.1                  2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA
 7            102130              275                 2               2.6                  1    NA    NA     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 8             94916              282                 2               1.1                  1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     2
 9             39148              282                 2               0                    1     2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
10             85004              266                 2               0                    0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# ℹ 734 more rows
```

Porém em outros CSV os números de linhas são diferentes e/ou tem colunas em ordem trocada, segue exemplo:

```
# A tibble: 788 × 24
   atletas.atleta_id atletas.jogos_num     G    DE    SG atletas.clube_id    CA    FC     A    DS    FF    FS atletas.rodada_id atletas.pontos_num    GS
               <int>             <int> <int> <int> <int>            <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>             <int>              <dbl> <int>
 1             37424                 2    NA    NA    NA             1371    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA                 2               1.84    NA
 2             72372                 0    NA    NA    NA              286    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA                 2               0       NA
 3             37656                 2    NA     2     2              266    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA                 2               6       NA
 4             96468                 2    NA     5    NA              285    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA                 2               1        3
 5             42234                 2    NA     9     1              264    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA                 2              11        1
 6             83257                 2     1    NA    NA              262     1    NA    NA    NA     1     2                 2               8.1     NA
 7            102130                 1    NA    NA    NA              275    NA    NA    NA     3    NA     1                 2               2.6     NA
 8             94916                 1    NA    NA    NA              282     1     2    NA    NA     2     2                 2               1.1     NA
 9             39148                 1     2    NA    NA              282    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     5                 2               0       NA
10             85004                 0    NA    NA    NA              266    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA                 2               0       NA
# ℹ 798 more rows
```

Sei que com o `cbind()` consigo uni-las desde que a ordem de colunas e o número de linhas sejam idênticos. Há alguma maneira mais pratica de fazer esse tratamento sem que seja manualmente uma por uma?

adicionei o vertor `main_info` que contém todos os `header()` das colunas que eu tenho interesse:

```
main_info<-c("atletas.atleta_id","atletas.clube_id","atletas.rodada_id","atletas.pontos_num","atletas.jogos_num","G","A","DS","DE","SG","GS","GC","CV","CA","FC","FF","FS","FT","PI","I","FD","PP","PC","PS")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que `df1` e `df2` são os nomes desses conjuntos de dados, faça:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- 
  df1 |> 
  full_join(df2, by = "atletas.atleta_id")
```

Todas as linhas de `df1` e `df2` serão mantidas em `df`, além de todas as colunas. Atletas presentes apenas no `df1` terão as observações referentes às colunas de `df2` preenchidas como `NA` e vice-versa.